# c# can a saved List<OwnObject> be deserialized in another application?

Tags: c#, serialization

Can a List that is saved in a .txt file be opened and deserialized in another application? 
The thing is that I have an .txt file that I know contains a List that has stored Products in it: `List<Products>.`
This list needs to be opened in an other application so the itemvalues from a product in the list can be listed.
I tried with the code below, but obviously it does not work because the object is an own created object with the name Product.

```
Stream s = File.Open(directory, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
List<object> fromFile = (List<object>)bf.Deserialize(s); 
str.Close();
```

I've tried to search for answers myself but I can't find any similar questions or answers and I don't know how to solve this issue, can you guys help me out?

Comment: The list should be saved in an understandable format in the file, i.e. json or xml.

Comment: You would need to load the original type in your new application or create your own type with the same deserialization behaviour (e.g same name and properties).

Comment: Yes it can use same serializer to deserialize and have same schema on other end, it shall work as expected

Comment: Deserializing it as a `List<object>` wouldn't be particularly useful, since `object` has no useful properties.  Have you tried deserializing it as a `List<Product>`?

Comment: Please note above code will work only if you have used same `BinaryFormatter` to serialize to file, it will mostly not work by using different serializers, for text like Json or Xml interoperability will be much higher

Comment: Thank you for quick responses!
This new application does not have a class named Product so no I have not tried deserializing it as List<Product>. 
It sounds like my only option is to add a class that has the same characteristics as the Product object or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need three things to be commonly understood by each application:

1. The serialization/deserialization algorithm
2. The format of data (XML, JSON, proprietary text, binary)
3. The data type `OwnType`

As comments indicate above, the first two are easily solvable and there are established libraries to help you with them.

#3 is more interesting, especially when:

a) You're implementing each application in a different language, and/or

b) The type `OwnType` evolves over time, making it inconsistent with files serialized in previous versions

Attempts to solve this entire set of problems have been made in several forms - there's [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and the almost-extinct [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), for example.

Comment: so I need to create the data type OwnType (or Product) in this other application too? 
There is like no way to just deserialize somehow so I can store the Objects in the List<> that is saved in the .txt file just so I can read the values in each object in the List<> ?

Comment: Think about it - if you're deserializing something into a data type, that type must have the attributes/fields to store that data in a usable form. Does an Object have all the fields your Product type has?

Comment: No probably not, thank you for your answer!
I will have to contact the person who has the other application and discuss the issue but now I atleast know how we can solve it :)